# How do I localize my app's name in the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I'd like to change the name of my app on the App Store for some of the localizations I handle.

I've already seen That I can change the name of the app on the springboard using CFBundleDisplayName and that works pretty well.
But there is nothing about the localization on the App Store.

Is CFBundleDisplayName doing the job ? Is there something else to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into iTunes Connect? I know that the description can be localized there (under Manage apps -> App -> Version -> Manage Localizations). I'm not entirely sure if it can be done though, as the names in the App Store have to be unique and therefore I imagine that are bound to a certain app ID.

Comment: The app name cannot be edited there but it may come from the CFBundleName or CFBundleDisplayName ... I don't know.And the other question is "what about unicity" of the app name is a good one :)

Comment: The one shown in App Store does not come from the bundle. Only the one shown on screen comes from the .plist.

Answer (score 0):

To localize the App Name you can do this like any other file. First click on the AppName-Info.plist file then open up the Identity Inspector (Left Pane Column), under the document tag is a Localization section. You can just click the add button to add the different languages that you want (say, first English, then Italian). Than you just have to individual change each of the names in the AppName-Info.plist (English) and AppName-Info.plist (Italian) files.

Comment: That way I have to remove what I did with the "Application has localized display name" key I suppose ? What about app name unicity ? Do I have to duplicate all keys or do I have to put only the keys I want to override (CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName) ? thx

Comment: The entire file would be automatically duplicated for you - then you would just update the name in the CFBundleDisplayName field to be the localized version.

Comment: I tried doing this but when compiling xcode looks for the AppName-Info.plist in the root directory of the app, not in the localized folders so I get an error