# Can I have App name as English + Some other language?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, naming-conventions

I have created an app for real estate.

My client is insisting on keeping the app name in both English and Arabic.

Is this possible in the App store?

The client is worrying that if the user searches app names in Arabic, they will not see the app as the name of the app is in English.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214556/how-do-i-localize-my-apps-name-in-the-app-store, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118281/iphone-app-localize-and-change-name-of-the-app-based-on-each-country-app-store, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871990/how-to-localize-bundle-display-name-in-iphone-app

Comment: @CodyGray : I am not talking about localization... I want the app name as "My App - بلدي التطبيق" (this is app name on home screen below icon)

Comment: I don't understand why localization is not the answer to your problem. If the user speaks English and has their iPhone configured to display English text, then they probably want to see "My App". If they have it configured for Arabic, then you can show them the Arabic name. It does me absolutely no good to have the Arabic name cluttering up my home screen, I can't read the language. The App Store understands and supports localized apps; search will work as expected.

Comment: @CodyGray : I think you didn't get my point. By App name means the name of the application on the app store. I know on main screen when I open app, name will be shown as per localization. but I want app name itself in English and arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a mixed English/Arabic name for the app in the Info.plist. The key you are looking for is “Bundle Display Name” (`CFBundleDisplayName`). By default that key value is `${PRODUCT_NAME}`, but you can change it to any string you want (even with Arabic characters).

Mind that the space in the home screen is limited, and you cannot use long names under the icons. Your proposed name seems to be a little bit long and shows like “My…التطبيق” in my Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the name in the display name in info.plist file [image: Check Image]